# Produce borderless image with the `dot` command of graphviz

Tags: crop, graphviz, dot, clip

Currently when I produce an image with graphviz, I get a border which is pretty hard to auto-remove without rasterizing the PDF:

```
echo 'digraph { a -> b }' | dot -Tpdf > output.pdf
```

Produces the following graphic, in which I have highlighted the borders in red.
These are areas which appear white on the original result but contain no meaningful information.

Is there any way to prevent `dot` from producing these borders instead of relying on additional packages to fix the issue downstream?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**margin** (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/margin/) seems to be causing the problem.  For many output formats, a small number is the default, for pdf, a larger margin is the default.

```
digraph {
graph [margin=0]
a -> b
}
```

This, however, will also remove the borders around any subgraphs. If you only want to remove the outer graph border, use:

```
digraph {
graph [margin=0]
a -> b
subgraph cluster0 {
   margin = 10;
   b -> c
   }
}
```

Sadly, though, there remains a thinner border around the outer edge of the figure, which is not controlled by either of the 2 margin specifications given above:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I edited the answer to add an example output and comment on possible side-effects of the parameter. However, this does not get rid of the outer margin entirely. Do you know how to prevent what's left from being generated? I'd need that to mark this as resolved.

Comment: Seemingly an undocumented feature/bug  This command line will eliminate *almost* all of the margin:  `dot myfile.gv | neato -n -Tpdf >myfile.pdf`  (see https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords)